# Tengo un listado de Acciones, Como pasar un el id del reg. elejido en la ventana principal a una ventana emergente popup, estoy trabajando con django

Tags: popup, ventana

```
Class Acciones(model.Model):
   `Fecha = models.DateTimeField()`
   `Cantidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)`
   `Valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)`

Class Documento(model.Model):
    `corresponde = models.ForeignKey(Acciones, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
    `Picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="documentos")`
```

Tengo un listado de Acciones en html con la opcion de elegir a cual registro quiero registrar documentos (Fotos) relacionados con el registro de Acciones, para tal efecto con js genero una ventana emergente popup, dado que al ser en django devo paras por una url.  El asunto es que he hecho lo poco que se de todo. En definitiva intento pasar el Id de Acciones a la ventana popup, para poder registrar en el documento a que Accion corresponde ese documento. Por favor si me puede ayudar, les agradezco.

Comment: Por favor, presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/597563/edit) y añade las etiquetas correspondientes al lenguaje de programación asociado a tu pregunta.